# How to access XSRF-TOKEN value from Laravel when using Sanctum

Tags: laravel, xss, slack-api, laravel-sanctum

I created a custom Slack app that is enabled from within my Vue/Laravel app, and, per the [Slack docs](https://api.slack.com/legacy/oauth) when enabling the app and authenticating via OAuth, you pass in a value as the `state` value, and when Slack calls your callback function, they pass that value back to you so you can check to make sure it the request isn't from someone else.

We were initially using Laravel's Passport, and passing the `XSRF-TOKEN` value as `state` from the front end (using `Cookies.get['XSRF-TOKEN')` from `js-cookie`), and then in the callback function on the back end, comparing that with the value from the `csrf_token()` function. However, after switching to Sanctum, the value returned from `csrf_token()` and `$request->cookie('XSRF-TOKEN')` is a different value, so that comparison fails. The only other way I have been able to get the token value on the back end is using the `$_COOKIES[XSRF-TOKEN`]` value, but I don't want to use globals, so I'm stuck.

It seems that I need to do one of two things:`

1. Find a way to get the actual value of `XSRF-TOKEN` in Laravel w/o using a global, or
2. Use another unique string

I would prefer the first option. Is there a way I can access the `XSRF-TOKEN` value from within Laravel when using Sanctum?

Answer (score 0):

No, and there shouldn't be. It would defeat the entire purpose of the CSRF token if an external site (in this case Slack) had the ability to **know** the token.

What you should do is much simpler: Add the `redirect_uri` to the `$except` array in the `VerifyCsrfToken` Middleware that is in your `app/Http/Middleware` folder.

```php
protected $except = [
    '/your-slack-callback-endpoint-here'
];
```